# Calculate balance from debit and credit column and select users in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have table accounts in which I have following 3 columns

users_id, debit, credit

I want to take out balance, so for that I need to check how many credit users have and then delete the debit from that and count as total balance for one user. And like this select all such users in one table, or total number of users with balance more than 1

I have done like this

```
    SELECT * , (
SUM( credit )
) - SUM( debit ) AS TotalBalance
FROM accounts
GROUP BY user_id
```

I want only users those who have more than one balance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  accounts
WHERE
  credit-debit > 1
```

Comment: I wan to take balance, so for that I need to check how many credit users have and then delete the debit from that and count as total balance for one user. And like this select all such users in one table, or total number of users with balance more than 1

Comment: Please update your question with specific example and desired output.